# What causes a website's alexa page-rank and traffic data to display highly regular sine wave patterns over a period of 30 days?

Tags: pagerank, traffic, alexa

At first I wondered if it was due to the traffic difference between day and night, but that turned out not to be the case, since the period of rise and drop in traffic was about a week, not overnight.

The website I'm looking at is [this one](http://cn.alexa.com/siteinfo/fx168.com) (it's not mine). Looks weird, right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but almost every single website will show clear 7 day patterns and trends for (for example) number of users. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm no expert in Chinese or finances, but it looks like fx168.com is a finance website and it seems like it's traffic peaks during the begging of the week and then wanes off until the next week starts again. It could have something to do with the Chinese stock markets or maybe when the Chinese receive their paychecks.